# jackson @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY) annotation not working for empty String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)`  at class level for a POJO with String fields. Usually the JSON response will not have String fields with null or empty values.

Documentation for `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)` states *For Java {@link java.lang.String}s, `length()` is called,
         *   and return value of 0 indicates empty String (note that `String.isEmpty()`
         *   was added in Java 1.6 and as such can not be used by Jackson*

But, in some cases the String fields with empty Strings are getting displayed. Is this a known issue?

Update : I m using Jackson 2.6.5. I dont see the above stated issue in my local environment, but only in QA. Unable to reproduce in local.

Exmaple Code :

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Domaion1 extends Domain {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7006824854691527605L;

    @JsonProperty("count")
    private String productCount;}
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Please provide a [mcve] and the version of Jackson you are using.

Comment: added @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Yeah, that works fine for me. Figure out what is different from: _but only in QA_.

Comment: At a guess, it sounds like it might be a classpath issue.  What servlet container or app server are you using in "QA"?  Also, validate the version of jackson getting included

Comment: The QA JSON repsonse shows the field as empty String.

Comment: He means figure out the difference in the environment

Comment: We are using cloud platform of Google

Comment: I confirmed, we are using same version of Jackson. Must be some edge case.